# Should ErrorCollector (which is part of JSR-303 functionality) in GWT 2.4 be redesigned?

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, gwt2, gwt-editors, gwt-2.4

I know this question is not about particular problem I have. It's rather question to GWT SDK team. As far as I remember StackOverflow is now their official communication channel with engineering community :)

**Problem:**

For aliased editors such as `ValueBoxEditorDecorator` you'll receive duplicate errors in your `HasEditorErrors.showErrors()` - one for ValueBoxEditorDecorator itself and another one for nested ValueBoxEditor. Current implementation of `ValueBoxEditorDecorator` iterates through list of errors and rejects ones that don't belong to nested editor. It looks like a hacky workaround to me :)

**Question:**

I think duplicates should be discarded somewhere earlier, for example in `SimpleViolation.pushViolations` or `DelegateMap.of` or `ErrorCollector.endVisit`.

Initially I thought why not just keep one delegate per unique `EditorContext.getAbsolutePath` and drop the rest. Then I realized that perhaps there is a use-case when ValueBoxEditorDecorator and its inner ValueBoxEditor would get different errors although I can't come up with the scenario how it can happen due to my short-time knowledge of gwt's sources.

So here is what I think. Why don't we use map in `ErrorCollector.errorStack` instead of `List` where the key will be combination of EditorError.getAbsolutePath() and EditorError.getUserData() ? It would solve two issues IMO:

- We won't need to filter out dupkicate errors in our editors.
- ErrorCollector.visit() won't assume that editors like this one are traversed in hierarchical order. I don't see anywhere in documentation that visitors would always work that way.

What do you think ?

Comment: The _official channel_ for GWT are the Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-web-toolkit-contributors In this particular case, use the second one.

Comment: EditorVisitor is expected to first `visit` a parent editor, then depending on the return value iterate on each one of the children, and then `endVisit` the editor. It's rather clear from the javadoc.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about duplicates? Should it be fixed?